# do Salesforce use Lightning Data Services in standard save procedure in Lightning?

Tags: lightning

When we save a record in Lightning and in the next second or two if we do change the same field again. Then there is an error stating - "This record was modified by 'username'  during your edit session. Make a note of data you entered, then reload the record and enter your updates again". Here username is the same as a logged-in user doing the updates. So, how Salesforce is doing the Save procedure?  (It's an intermittent issue).

Comment: The problem is probably caused by a process or a trigger updating the current record before or after save.

Comment: Your point is correct @MartinLezer. One thing to add, why it is not reproducible in lower orgs and only in Production. Just curious.